# How pure is this chloroform?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

hopefully this question is in the right place.

I'm a biologist not a chemist (so sorry if this is a stupid question!)- I'm doing some RNA extractions from brain tissue which requires the use of Chloroform. In the manual, it specifies:

Chloroform must not contain isoamyl alcohol or other additives and must be pure.

This is what it says on the label:
[image]

[image]

Does this count as 'pure'? Obviously pure is quite a subjective term, but it doesn't to my eye contain any isoamyl alcohol, so I suspect it should be OK - but I thought it best to check.

Comment: Note that this grade of chloroform is stabilised with amylene. Can you get HPLC grade? That would be purer.

Comment: Yes, I imagine that I would be able to get it - I'm just not sure whether I would _need_ it.

Comment: Amylene is a pentene. I would guess that it is not going to react with RNA or other biological materials

Comment: To what do phosgene and amylene react? Alcohols give the respective carboxylate diesters.

Comment: Depends on amylene content which may only be a few hundred ppm. I'd use it